# How do I pass parent component into child component in Angular 7 via @Input()

Tags: angular

Using Angular 7,

I have a component that has an input property that is an object it interogates for some information.

```html
<app-details [item]="whatGoeHere" key="firstName"></app-details>
```

In the component I then have a input property like so...

```js
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit{

    @Input() item: any;
    @Input() key: string;

    ngInit(){
      if(this.item && this.item.isYummy){
       ....
      }
    }
    ...
}
```

When the object I want to pass in is some property of the parent component then I just supply a property name on the parent component and all is good.

But, what if I want to pass in the parent component instance itself rather than one of it's properties? How can the be done?

In some cases it will not be the parent component instance but one of its properties so I want to be able to specify in the binding rather than always referring to the parent.

In KnockoutJs I can use $data, $root to refer to the binding context. Is there a similar concept in Angular?

Comment: `ngAfterViewChecked` life cycle hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the host's html

```html
<app-details [item]="whatGoeHere" key="firstName" [context]="this"></app-details>
```

And define the input property inside the component

```js
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit{

    @Input() item: any;
    @Input() key: string;
    @Input() context;

    ngInit(){
      if(this.item && this.item.isYummy){
       ....
      }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: this! Pretty obvious now and exactly what I need. I'd assumed there was some weird angular syntax.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to pass the whole parent component? what are you planning to do with the parent inside of the child?

My first reaction is: you shouldn't be wanting to pass the whole parent to a child as you will end up with 2 tightly coupled components.

You can check [Angular's docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) about how to make your component interact, where you'll see the following alternatives and more.

### To make the parent listen for child events

Pass a function from the parent to the child. The child can invoke that function to talk to the parent:

```
<app-details (myCallback)="parentFunction()" key="firstName"></app-details>;
```

Angular's documentation for doing this is [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

### To make bi-directional communication between parent and child

Use a service if what you want is bi-directional communication. You can change data in the service from the child, and have the parent subscribe to changes. The parent could also send changes to the service with some other method, and you can have the child subscribe for those changes too.

Angular's documentation for doing this is [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

Comment: Big red flag for passing the parent to the child is noted. The reason is the parent component in this case happens to implement an interface that the child component will call some members of. In other cases it won't be the parent component.

Comment: Could you pass the individual members as outputs to the child component?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the context of the parent component to the child component as an Input.

I have created stackblitz answer. Check this out...

[pass parent component to child](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrstrz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)